# How to get the cloud foundry app instance's guid?

Tags: guid, cloud-foundry

The Cloud Foundry App /stats api (/v2/apps/:guid/stats) gives the details of each Instance of the CF App.

But it only gives the Instance Index (eg: "0", "1", "2" etc)

CF App Stats API:http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/222/apps/get_detailed_stats_for_a_started_app.html

```
GET on https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/apps/<app-guid>/stats
```

Sample response:

```
{
    "0":
    {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "stats":
        {
            "name": "testlibappcf",
            "uris":
            [
                "testlibappcf.mybluemix.net"
            ],
            "host": "169.54.206.30",
            "port": 61814,
            "uptime": 84972,
            "mem_quota": 536870912,
            "disk_quota": 1073741824,
            "fds_quota": 16384,
            "usage":
            {
                "time": "2015-10-29 08:25:45 +0000",
                "cpu": 0.0015772999557422517,
                "mem": 181530624,
                "disk": 187355136
            }
        }
    },
    "1":
    {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "stats":
        {
            "name": "testlibappcf",
            "uris":
            [
                "testlibappcf.mybluemix.net"
            ],
            "host": "75.126.172.157",
            "port": 61588,
            "uptime": 263802,
            "mem_quota": 536870912,
            "disk_quota": 1073741824,
            "fds_quota": 16384,
            "usage":
            {
                "time": "2015-10-29 08:25:45 +0000",
                "cpu": 0.002226168338735689,
                "mem": 184090624,
                "disk": 187158528
            }
        }
    },
    "2":
    {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "stats":
        {
            "name": "testlibappcf",
            "uris":
            [
                "testlibappcf.mybluemix.net"
            ],
            "host": "50.22.22.171",
            "port": 61970,
            "uptime": 74472,
            "mem_quota": 536870912,
            "disk_quota": 1073741824,
            "fds_quota": 16384,
            "usage":
            {
                "time": "2015-10-29 08:25:45 +0000",
                "cpu": 0.0019144080402859489,
                "mem": 213286912,
                "disk": 187158528
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since each Application instance lives inside a Warden container, is there a way to get the CF App Instance Id (container-guid)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that you need the instance id?

Comment: I am trying to do a random instance shutdown to test application recovery. For logging, I want the instance's guid as well as host for debug purposes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Applications in Cloud Foundry have GUIDs, the individual instances do not.

Comment: Ok, so from the sample response that I have posted in my question, does the {"host": "169.54.206.30"} for App instance Id index "0" point to the public IP address of the Warden container in which it is running?

Comment: It points to the internal IP address of the Warden container.

Comment: Confusingly Cloud Foundry itself uses the name [CF_INSTANCE_GUID](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#CF-INSTANCE-GUID) for the UUID of the particular instance of the app.

Comment: index combined with guid makes it possible to find unique instance

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is now out-of-date.

Cloud Foundry now exposes instance GUID via [`CF_INSTANCE_GUID`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#CF-INSTANCE-GUID).

Comment: and INSTANCE_INDEX tells you who is processing your request

Comment: Is there any api which returns all instance guid for app? Is instance guid unique after instance restart ?